# How to pass INT value from Activity A to Activity B with the Intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-recyclerview, integer

I want to pass an int from my MainActivity to a RecipeDetails Activity showing it in a TextBox.

I implemented the onClick method from MainActivity passing the value then I tried to get that value in the other Activity setting it in my TextBox. 
This method works if I try with other strings values from my DB.

```
    public void onClick(int position) {

    Intent MyEditIntent = new 
    Intent(MainActivity.this,RecipeDetails.class);

    MyEditIntent.putExtra("recipe_target", 
    recipeList.get(position).getTargetPeople());
    startActivity(MyEditIntent);
}
************************************************************
int recipeTarget = getIntent().getIntExtra("recipe_target", 0);
************************************************************
targetView = findViewById(R.id.targetView);
targetView.setText(recipeTarget);
```

Comment: What's the problem, exactly? Are you not getting the expected value in `recipeTarget`? Or are you asking why it's crashing?

Comment: I'm asking why it's crashing

Comment: You cannot call `setText()` with an arbitrary integer value. You need to convert it to a `String` first; e.g., `targetView.setText(Integer.toString(recipeTarget))`.